# add link to each image with jquery

Tags: jquery

how can I add a share link to each of the image simiar to the first image in below example:

https://jsfiddle.net/w1h6mhp8/4/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".copy-url").click(function() {
    $(this).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
  })
  
  if(true) {  //will be replaced by navigator.share, value will be url
    $("div.copy-url").each(function() {
      var img =$(this);
      var imgval = $('.copy-url').val;
      var sharer = "<a class="share">" + imgval + "</span>";
      $(this).append(sharer)
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input type="text" class="copy-url" value="222222" readonly="yes">
<span class="share">copy</span> <a class="share" href="222222">share</a></div>

<div><input type="text" class="copy-url" value="333333" readonly="yes">
<span class="share">copy</span></div>

<div><input type="text" class="copy-url" value="444444" readonly="yes">
<span class="share">copy</span></div>

<div><input type="text" class="copy-url" value="555555" readonly="yes">
<span class="share">copy</span></div>

<div><input type="text" class="copy-url" value="666666" readonly="yes">
<span class="share">copy</span></div>
```

Comment: There is no `div class="copy-url">` in your HTML code + many other mistakes.

Comment: Also you are trying to end a link with a span tag `"<a class="share">" + imgval + "</span>"`

Comment: You've also got mismatched quotes in the string you concatenate

Comment: `image` ?! which image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do as you want:

```
$("div .copy-url").each(function() {
  var imgval = $(this).find('.copy-url').val();
  var sharer = "<a class='share' href='"+imgval+"'>share</a>";
  $(this).append(sharer)
});
```

You had the following mistakes:

- You had mismatching quotes in `"<a class="share">"` should be `"<a class='share'>"`
- In the line `$('.copy-url').val` you are missing `$(this).find` and `()` after your .val. Should be `$(this).find('.copy-url').val()`
- You have no `div` with the class `copy-url` in your code.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".copy-url").click(function() {
    $(this).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
  })

  if (true) { //will be replaced by navigator.share, value will be url
    $("div").each(function() {
      var imgval = $(this).find('.copy-url').val();
      var sharer = "<a class='share' href='"+imgval+"'>share</a>";
      $(this).append(sharer)
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input type="text" class="copy-url" value="222222" readonly="yes">
  <span class="share">copy</span> </div>

<div><input type="text" class="copy-url" value="333333" readonly="yes">
  <span class="share">copy</span></div>

<div><input type="text" class="copy-url" value="444444" readonly="yes">
  <span class="share">copy</span></div>

<div><input type="text" class="copy-url" value="555555" readonly="yes">
  <span class="share">copy</span></div>

<div><input type="text" class="copy-url" value="666666" readonly="yes">
  <span class="share">copy</span></div>
```